# Setting value of named range in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, named-ranges

I apologize if this is a total noob question. I'm in the process of writing an addin for Excel. I have a sub inside class1 that opens an excel file, in this sub I have a reference to sub2 which is below. All I am looking to do is hook into the active instance of Excel, change a named range value and exit. But I keep getting errors no matter which way that I try. Here is what I have. Tell me where I have gone wrong. Forgot to mention, this is in VB.NET.

```
   Private Sub SetRangeValue(ByVal RangeName As String, ByVal RangeValue As String)
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim TheRange As Excel.Range
    Dim TheRangeName As String = ""

    'Hook into running excel instance
    ExcelApp = CType(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)

    'First Attempt Here
    TheRange = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(RangeName)
    TheRange.Value = RangeValue

    'Second Attempt
    TheRange = ExcelApp.Range(RangeName)
    TheRange.Value = RangeValue
End Sub
```

I can't get either one to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what errors you are getting?

Comment: not really sure.  It keeps giving me errors related to the com object

Comment: Here it is. This is with (First Attempt) Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020846-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: This is the second error.  COM Exception was unhandled Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got this to work properly.  This is how it needed to work.  Thanks for all the help.

```
Private Sub SetRangeValue(ByVal RangeName As String, ByVal RangeValue As String)
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    'Dim TheRangeObj As Excel.Range
    Dim TheRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name
    Dim TheRangeName As String = ""


    'Hook into running excel instance
    ExcelApp = CType(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)

    TheRange = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(RangeName)
    TheRange.RefersToRange.Value = RangeValue

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'First Attempt Here
TheRange = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(RangeName)
TheRange.Value = RangeValue
```

According to [Names.Item Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192981.aspx), this function returns a single Name object from a Names collection. In this case TheRange is not valid name for this variable, it should be TheName. Then

```
TheName.Value = RangeValue
```

is not right assignment; According to [Name.Value Property (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195389.aspx) this property - Returns or sets a String value that represents the formula that the name is defined to refer to.

Error 0x800A03EC, there are a number of reasons this error is returned from Excel - the most common is when  attempts to write data larger than Excel can handle. For example, you try to write a string longer than 1024 characters to a cell in Excel

Answer (score 0):

I just made a sub that would make it easier me to find & replace using my named ranges:

```
Private Sub XlFindReplace(ByRef xSheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal cellName As String, ByVal NewText As String)
        xSheet.Range(cellName).Value = NewText
    End Sub
```

then T'd call it like this in order to replace stuff:

```
XlFindReplace(xlC1Sheet, "client1Co1Tax", client1Co1Tax)
```

- where the `xlC1Sheet` is the sheet I'm currently
- the `"client1Co1Tax"`is the name of the range in excel
- and `client1Co1Tax` is the string variable I'm replacing it

Thanks to everyone for their input.